# CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR related to memory

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to run a model in keras with a large image dataset of 2k items, 3GBs approx. (Keras 2.3.1, TF 1.14.0, CUDA 10.0, CuDNN 7.4 on a RTX2080).
Whenever I try to run it I get the following error:

```
2020-10-26 19:12:47.286751: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-10-26 19:12:47.447483: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-10-26 19:12:48.102455: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2020-10-26 19:12:48.104974: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

The thing is no matter how much I narrow down the model size or if I only pass a little subset of the dataset to the network it thorws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting your PC? This saved me many times from mysterious CUDNN errors.

Also I see similar errors when I have TF already imported in anther running process (like in a console in PyCharm for example), but you'll resolve this with the restart as well.

If that doesn't solve the issue, try some tutorial/example code from TensorFlow website, this will confirm or deny that it's your code causing the issue. If you still have the same issue with TensorFlow then I'd try reinstalling the environment. If you don't have the same issue than your best bet is trying to narrow it down as much as possible and then posting minimal runnable code example that produces your error into your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I havce restarted the pc many times, tutorials work, I've done various fresh installs ... The enviroment doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Well that's good news, if tutorials work and your code doesn't, you can then take your code and systematically remove chunks until you find what triggers your error.